# how to prevent hapijs query parameter parsing from converting dates

Tags: hapi.js

I am using hapijs but the following query parameter got converted:

when I request something like: url?mydate=2016-03-14T23:05:30Z

```
const mydate = request.query.mydate
```

to my surprise, mydate is not 2016-03-14T23:05:30Z

instead it had become "Mon Mar 14 2016 23:05:30 GMT+0000 (UTC)"

obviously some sort of conversion happened in parsing the query parameter. i wonder if there is a way to just get my original date string. thanks!

Comment: Do you have validation applied to that route? I doubt hapi would just convert it automatically. Without explicit validation, it's just another string.

Comment: ah yes, thanks. it must because i have Joi validation. I will test that.

Comment: yes, it was the joi validation.thank you so much matt!